# Append string to the query result

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, string

I have a scenario where I want to append a string 'rajat' at the beginning of all the values fetched from database. Query looks like

```
('rajat' + (SELECT a FROM b 
        WHERE b >= (SELECT TOP 1 c FROM d ORDER BY e DESC)))
```

but this doesn't seems to work.

Comment: What is the datatype of column `a`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT a = 'rajat' + tableB.a
FROM dbo.b tableB
WHERE tableB.b >= (SELECT TOP 1 c FROM d ORDER BY e DESC)
```

Comment: @mr_eclair: a white-space? Why? OP has also slapped together both.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming a different datatype for column `a`

```
SELECT 'rajat ' + cast(a as varchar(50)) as a
WHERE b >= (SELECT TOP 1 c FROM d ORDER BY e DESC)
```

simple and straight forward if column a is varchar.

```
SELECT 'rajat ' + a as a
WHERE b >= (SELECT TOP 1 c FROM d ORDER BY e DESC)
```